# How to end a RDP session without locking in windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

When I use "`C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#NNN /dest:console`"
I get the following error:

> Could not connect sessionID 1 to sessionname console, Error code
>   Error [7041]:Disconnecting the console session is not supported.

I searched for a solution and found nothing.
maybe there is another tool, apart from `tscon`, to help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have a 2003 box to test with, but maybe this will work:

Start your RDP session with `mstsc /console /v:servername` and then try the `tscon` command again.

If that doesn't work, try `mstsc /admin /v:servername` instead.